# Exception handling with Scala Future failed scenario

Tags: scala, future

I have the following test method

```
def test() = {
val aa = Future{10} map {
  case x if x%2 == 0 => (x,x)
  case _ => val kk = Future.failed(BadRequestException("dd")); kk
 }
 aa
}
```

If I remove the `case _` then the return type of method is `Future[(Int, Int)]` which is exactly what I want. However, when I add the `case _` scenario the return type becomes `Future[Object]`. I am not able to understand what should I change as other similar methods in our code base do similar things(I am sure I am missing something subtle) and the return type remains of the nature `Future[(Int, Int)]`. Afterall, when I am throwing an exception for a scenario, I would not want the return type of the method to be changed. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `flatMap` instead of `map` as shown below. with `map` method the return type of `case _` is `Future[BadRequestException]` and for `case x if x%2 == 0` the return type is `(Int, Int)`. This is leading you to have a net return type of `Future[Object]`.  This can be corrected by using the flatMap instead of map as shown below.

```
def test() = Future{10} flatMap {
  case x if x%2 == 0 => Future.successful((x,x))
  case _ => Future.failed(BadRequestException("dd"))
 }
```

Comment: oh Good catch, I got it now, as to rather than return tuple, I can return Future of it and then flatMapping it takes care of it otherwise I will get `Future[Future..`. I understand that part. What I still don't get is, why is the compiler happy now and agrees to the return type I want.

Comment: because in the two case the return types are `Future[(Int, Int)]` and `Future[BadRequestException]` and the union of this return type is `Future[(Int, Int)]`. whereas in your original map operation two return types were `Future[(Int, Int)]` and `Future[Future[BadRequestException]]` which translates to an union type of `Future[Object]`

Comment: Where can I read about this a little more. Thanks a lot for such concise and clear explanation.  I want to read about which union types result in which ultimate type

Comment: You could also throw an exception instead of returning Future.failed and then you can avoid flat mapping your future.. 

```def test() = Future{10} map {
  case x if x%2 == 0 => (x,x)
  case _ => throw new BadRequestException("dd")
 }```